# ImageOps Module missing in PIL?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am trying to save images in Django and getting the error "The ImageOps module could not be imported"

For some reason I am unable to import or use the ImageOps Module from PIL in the django shell. I have tried deleting the egg and reinstalling PIL but that doesn't work. I looked inside the egg and ImageOps.py is there and everything looks fine when I go inside of it.

Anybody know why I would lose access to a single module like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was being caused by django StdImageField. In site-packages/stdimage/fields.py line 71 I changed

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
```

to:

```
import Image, ImageOps
```

Now everything works fine.